# C# software wont connect to my localhost mysql Xampp says sqlException was unhandled

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm done designing my project software that passes information in my software textbox to my local mysql xampp database.

im have this error message

[image: sqlException was unhandled]

Please help with the code below. What am i getting wrong from the code below?

I have two textboxes namely "seed" and "password" and button "encrypt" and "decrypt"

```
namespace seed
{
    public partial class CryptSeed : Form
    {
        public CryptSeed()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=seedcrypt;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=seed;");

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = "INSERT INTO info ('id','seed','password','ip') VALUES (NULL,'"+seed.Text+ "','" +password.Text+ "',NULL)";
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY !!! ");  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception message in your _screen shot_ indicates a network failure talking to _SQL Sever_. You're using the wrong library for connecting to your database and/or do not have either your database or your connection string (or both) set up correctly.

90% of the code in your example has _nothing to do_ with what you're asking, and you aren't including the relevant error information in your actual question - please have a look at http://sscce.org/.

Comment: The MySQL connector for C# is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to mysql database you got it all wrong.First you need mysqlconnector for c#.
Second what exactly are you trying to do?save?read?

```
 public partial class CryptSeed : Form
{
    public CryptSeed()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }
       //you will need to specify the port Mysql uses:3306

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
           //  If you are saving data you cant do it here.
          //  But still will show you how to do it in a button //click 
     //event.                
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;  username=seedcrypt;database=seed;password=xxxxxxx");
           string query = "INSERT INTO 
          info('id','seed','password','ip') VALUES 
         (NULL,'"+seed.Text+ "','" +password.Text+ "',NULL)";
         con.Open();
          MysqlCommand cmd = new 
          MysqlCommand(query,con);
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con.Close();
          MessageBox.Show("INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY !!! 
            ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please im trying to save to database ...im not reading .... Pls can you provide me codes i can use in visual studio 2015 ....with two textbox names as "seed" and "password" and two buttons "encrypt" and "decrypt" plss... Its a project i need to submit asap

Comment: How can i get in touch with you can get your mail or whatsapp number ??

Comment: What do you need to encrypt and decrypt.?? When do you want to encrypt and decrypt.?? In code you provided you will save it plain. Try saving data with my code then i can assist from there.